# Mac is confused as to which version of Ruby is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I can't tell what's going on here. When I run:

```
ruby -v
```

I get the following output:

```
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Then when I try to open the Rails Console:

```
rails console
```

I get this error:

```
Rails 5 requires Ruby 2.2.2 or newer.

You're running
  ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

**So am I running 2.4.0 or 2.0.0?!** And how do I make it so that `rails console` is happy + works?!

---

#### Update

Output of several commands:

```
which rails
/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/rails

bundle exec rails console
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

type -all ruby
ruby is /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby
ruby is /usr/bin/ruby

rbenv local
-bash: rbenv: command not found

rvm -v
rvm 1.29.1 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io/]
```

Comment: What is the result of `which rails`? Have you run `bundle install`? What happens if you run `bundle exec rails console`? What happens if you run `type -all ruby`?

Comment: How many versions of Ruby do you have installed? Are you using a tool (such as rbenv or rvm) that lets you have multiple versions of Ruby installed?

Comment: what version manager do u use ? rvm or rbenv ? try `cd ..` and back to folder `cd folder_name`

Comment: Thanks @TomLord (+1) please see my updates above...does that help you out at all?

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort (+1) - I'm not actively using either rbenv or rvm but if you look at my updates above you'll see that rbenv isn't installed whereas rvm is. Does that help you out at all?

Comment: Thanks @7urkm3n (+1) I'm not actively using either rbenv or rvm but if you look at my updates above you'll see that rbenv isn't installed whereas rvm is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.rvm` in your `which rails` output:

```
/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/rails
              ^^^^
```

says that you are using RVM to manage your Ruby versions. If you say `rvm list` in a shell, you should see both 2.4.0 and 2.0.0 in the list of available Rubies and the current version in that list should change when you enter your Rails application's directory.

Check the `Gemfile`, it should say:

```
ruby '2.4.0'
```

or similar so make sure it is using the right version. Also look for a `.ruby-version` file and make sure it says the right thing (if it exists).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rbenv you can change your ruby version for a specific project by using

```
rbenv local (ruby-version)
```

For a list of ruby versions you can use

```
rbenv install -l
```

Found a mini tutorial on changing using rbenv to change ruby versions here:
https://makandracards.com/makandra/21545-rbenv-how-to-switch-to-another-ruby-version-temporarily-per-project-or-globally